# What is the optimum way to save FCM messages?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to FCM and I want to build a chat app with FCM and PHP as my server and Mysql for my database.

I got the tokens from FCM and stored them in mysql in respect to each user's id, great! my question is where do i save the chat messages?

Do I save them in my sql database to retrieve later in my app or does FCM does that automatically? What exactly is the default procedure?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should save the messages on your MySQL database. Later, if you want to retrieve them from your app, create some GET calls on your webservice to do that.

I'm also new with FCM, this is what I would do.